# is there a way to know if a CPU process is thrashing?

Tags: memory, cpu

I see the following line:

```
 PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 20   0   52.2g  39.9g    388 S  1554 63.5   1663:21 MATLAB
```

on top, for a CPU process I am runinng on a computer with 64GB of memory.

The process has been slow, but it is also very intensive. What I am wondering now - is it thrashing because of swapping memory to disk, or can I trust it is still executing in semi-full force? I have no idea how to check for that -- the machine is not next to me, so I can't listen for heightened harddisk activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure, you would need to turn on the vMajor column (vMj) in top (<kbd>f</kbd>) and see if the numbers are high.

However, if you have 64G of ram and this is only using 52G of virtual memory and only 40G is resident (with 63% memory use), it is almost certainly not thrashing.  If it was thrashing, I'd expect a much higher %MEM and VIRT should be much larger than your physical memory.

Also, a truly thrashing process would have %CPU below 10% (and this is 15x 100%).  So this process (thread group) is successfully keeping 15 cores busy, despite any possible disk pressures.